# Duplicate declaration of method 'applicationDidBecomeActive:

Tags: xcode, duplicates

I'm trying to integrate this Facebook sdk code:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  return YES;
}
```

In appdelegate.m I have the following error:

> Duplicate declaration of method 'applicationDidBecomeActive:'

What should I do ? I'm using Xcode 9 and I can't understand where is the problem. This is my entire appdelegate.m file so you can see in detail.

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppController.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "EAGLView.h"
#import "PTPAppDelegate.h"

#import "RootViewController.h"

#import "GameKit/GKLocalPlayer.h"
#import "GameKit/GKScore.h"
#import "GameKit/GKAchievement.h"

#import "models/PTModelController.h"


@implementation AppController
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize window;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

// cocos2d application instance
static PTPAppDelegate s_sharedApplication;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    PTModelController *mc = PTModelController::shared();
    mc->clean();
    mc->loadFile( "data/PTModelGeneralSettings.0.attributes.xml", PTModelController::Attributes );
    mc->loadFile( "data/PTModelFont.0.attributes.xml", PTModelController::Attributes );     
    mc->loadFile( "data/PTModelScreen.0.attributes.xml", PTModelController::Attributes );
    mc->loadFile( "data/PTModelObjectLabel.0.attributes.xml", PTModelController::Attributes );
    mc->loadFile( "data/PTModelObjectLoadingBar.0.attributes.xml", PTModelController::Attributes );
    mc->loadFile( "data/PTModelScreen.0.connections.xml", PTModelController::Connections );

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    EAGLView *__glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame: [window bounds]
                                        pixelFormat: kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                        depthFormat: GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16
                                 preserveBackbuffer: YES
                                         sharegroup: nil
                                      multiSampling: NO
                                    numberOfSamples: 0];

    __glView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

    // Use RootViewController manage EAGLView 
    viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    viewController.view = __glView;


    if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 6.0) {
        [window addSubview: viewController.view];
    }
    else  {
        [window setRootViewController:viewController];
    }

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden: YES];

//    [EventHandling observeAllEventsWithObserver:self withSelector:@selector(eventFired:)];

    printf("GL_VENDOR:     %s\n", glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
    printf("GL_RENDERER:   %s\n", glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
    printf("GL_VERSION:    %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    cocos2d::CCApplication::sharedApplication()->run();
    //clean up main model controller before starting loading Objects form XML files
    mc->clean();
    return YES;
}



-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    else  /* iphone */
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pause();
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->resume();
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    cocos2d::CCApplication::sharedApplication()->applicationDidEnterBackground();
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    cocos2d::CCApplication::sharedApplication()->applicationWillEnterForeground();
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

}

- (void)loadingDidComplete{

}

-(void)showCustomFullscreenAd{

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Free up as much memory as possible by purging cached data objects that can be recreated (or reloaded from disk) later.
     */
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty much self explanatory. You have implemented the "applicationDidBecomeActive" twice in there.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->resume();
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

Merge your two methods into only one. It should be looking like this.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->resume();
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

Finally, decide by yourself which line of code should be there first. In some cases it is vital to follow a specific order.

Comment: Oh god how I did not see it, forgive me but in this area I'm still new, thank you very much anyway for the help!